# Cygwin rsync protocol error

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I get an error with cygwin rsync trying to transfer files between 64bit windows and 64bit linux. Both machines have rsync 3.0.7 installed. I'm running rsync with ssh (no daemon involved). I see that the connection to the remote box is established, but rsync dies after authentication and before file transfer.

What could cause this problem?

```
C:\>rsync user@host:~/file newfile
Password:
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=
3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /home/lapo/packagi
ng/rsync-3.0.6-1/src/rsync-3.0.6/io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the windows git installation (mysysgit). Git on windows came with it's own ssh.exe and it's path was before cygwin path so rsync defaulted to git's ssh. The solution was simply swaping git bin and cygwin's bin dir in env PATH.

Comment: Good catch, I had the same error and searched for hours!

Answer (score 1):

The `error 12` with `rsync` means that the connection to remote party is gone. The reason depends on the environment.

If you are running rsync as a daemon, see its log file for clues. Is there enough free space on the remote system's disk? Maybe running `rsync` with `-v` parameter says something useful?

Comment: rsync not running as daemon. there is enough space and nothing useful from -vvv.

Comment: @kefeizhou: Is the remote system running `rsync` as a daemon?

Comment: @Dennis: there's no daemon on the remote system, i'm running rsync with ssh.